# Using 'lest' in a sentence

Tags: phrases, word-usage, sentence

a quick question:

> Don't let the sun go down in your heart, my child, lest fear and woe
>   would follow in your wake.

Is the above sentence correct, mainly the 'lest' part? English is not my native language. I am also uncertain about the use of the word 'would'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Proofreading requests are explicitly off-topic for this site; however, if you can identify a specific issue— *why* do you think lest is or isn't correct as used here? — we may be able to help. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: @choster The OP **did** identify a specific issue.

Comment: @Mick Specifying the issue would be "I've seen X used in A and B, but it's not used that way in C and D, so I'm not sure whether X is right here. I tried Googling the difference, but there weren't any useful results." Or, "According to N, *lest* is used this in W way, but here it seems to be used in X way. I don't understand whether X is correct or not here." There is no such context provided here.

Comment: Can you then point me to the forum where I can ask questions like this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's: "lest fear and woe follow in your wake". "Lest" is followed by an infinitive phrase with a bare infinitive. Otherwise it's fine !

Comment: As @tchrist has said, "We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers."

Comment: In fact, though I wouldn't consider 'lest fear and woe _would_ ...' acceptable nowadays, lest may also take 'should' (see the Swan example and Collins link).

Answer (score 0):

> The conjunction **'lest**' has a similar meaning to **'in case'** or
>   **'so that...not'.**
>
> If we rewrite the sentence using 'so that...not', the meaning will be
>   clearer:
>   ***Don't let the sun go down in your heart, my child, so that fear and woe wouldn't follow in your wake.***

The use 'lest' is very rare in modern British English; it is a little more common in formal American English.

> **Lest** can be followed by a subjunctive verb.
>
> *The government should take immediate action, **lest** the problem of child poverty **grow** worse.*

[image]

***Screen shot from Michael Swan's PEU***

Comment: You are correct about the need for a subjunctive (except that it is not optional). A [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lest) providing supporting evidence would help.

Comment: I have added a screen shot from the grammar PEU by Michael Swan. Thanks.

Comment: @Mick You'd better point this out to both Swan & [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lest): 'lest ...
conj (subordinating; takes should or a subjunctive verb).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My go-to source of all authority is Cambridge (Oxford if I absolutely have to). I'm too lazy to shop around.

Comment: @Mick  'except that it is not optional' is a very shaky arrogation, especially after Swan has given a counterexample. 'According to CDO it is not optional' is, with the link, acceptable and useful. // It has repeatedly been said on ELU that recognised grammars almost always trump dictionaries on grammaticality So one has to go above Swan (McCawley, perhaps).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was being facetious in my last comment.